# How can I obtain the ID from the following example string?

Tags: php

I use the following method to pad out a ID for a property on our website:

```
function generateAgentRef($id,$length=5,$strPrefix='1'){
    return $strPrefix . str_pad($id,$length,0,0);
}
```

Basically it will prefix 1 and then pad out the id with 0's until the string reaches $length.

But, I now have a requirement to revert this process. For example if I have the following IDs: 100650,100359,100651,100622,100112,100687, how can I get the ID e.g. 650, 359, 651, 622, 112, 687?

Hope this explains what I'm trying to achieve.

The ID in the database will never start with 0, so I was thinking of iterating over the components of the string and detecting when I hit something other than 0 and then splitting the string.

Answer (score 1):

substract 100000 from the generated ref and `intval()` it could work if the length is 6 numbers exactly.

Answer (score 0):

try using this
$a = substr($num,3);

here $num is the id you get
$a will be your desired number i.e 100659 shortened to 659

Comment: The ID could be greater than 3 characters.

Comment: in that case you can try this 
$a = substr($num,1);// this to get rid of prefix
$a = intval($a);// this will convert string 00659 into integer 659

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on your initial function

```
function getAgentId($id, $length = 5, $strPrefix = 1){
    return $id - generateAgentRef(0, $length, $strPrefix);
}

$id = generateAgentRef(255);
echo $id, PHP_EOL; // 100255
echo getAgentId($id), PHP_EOL; //255
```